# Cannot read property 'installed' of undefined express js

Tags: node.js, express, google-sheets

I have not been able to find an example of this issue with Express js or with the google sheets api. I am running an express application which is receiving a POST req I then pass it to a function which uses oAuth2 then sends the data as an appended row to a google sheet

when I call updateSheet() I get the following error

```
UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Cannot read property 'installed' of undefined
    at resolve (C:\Users\luther\Desktop\Pantree\index.js:50:69)
    at new Promise (<anonymous>)
    at authorize (C:\Users\luther\Desktop\Pantree\index.js:49:10)
    at updateSheet (C:\Users\luther\Desktop\Pantree\index.js:91:28)
    at app.post (C:\Users\luther\Desktop\Pantree\index.js:161:5)
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (C:\Users\luther\Desktop\Pantree\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
    at next (C:\Users\luther\Desktop\Pantree\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:137:13)
    at Route.dispatch (C:\Users\luther\Desktop\Pantree\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:112:3)
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (C:\Users\luther\Desktop\Pantree\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
    at C:\Users\luther\Desktop\Pantree\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:281:22
```

I do not know why this error occurs when posting because the error is thrown in my authorize() call which works perfectly when getting the initial data from the sheet.

I have updated the google sheets API scope to allow reading and writing as show below.
I am using dummy data in my resource object to rule out the issue being with body parser so currently all I am doing from my post request is calling updateSheet() with no arguments

```
const SCOPES = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets'];
const TOKEN_PATH = 'token.json';


// Load client secrets from a local file.
fs.readFile('client_secret.json', (err, content) => {
  if (err) return console.log('Error loading client secret file:', err);
  // Authorize a client with credentials, then call the Google Sheets API.
  authorize(JSON.parse(content), grabSheetData);
});

/**
 * Create an OAuth2 client with the given credentials, and then execute the
 * given callback function.
 * @param {Object} credentials The authorization client credentials.
 * @param {function} callback The callback to call with the authorized client.
 */
function authorize(credentials) {
  return new Promise(resolve => {  // Added
    const { client_secret, client_id, redirect_uris } = credentials.installed;
    const oAuth2Client = new google.auth.OAuth2(client_id, client_secret, redirect_uris[0]);

    // Check if we have previously stored a token.
    fs.readFile(TOKEN_PATH, (err, token) => {
      if (err) return getNewToken(oAuth2Client, e => resolve(e)); 
      oAuth2Client.setCredentials(JSON.parse(token));
      resolve(oAuth2Client); 
    });
  });
}


/* GET SHEET DATA */
async function grabSheetData () {
  var data = {
    payload: ''
  }
  const authClient = await authorize(creds);  
  const request = {
    spreadsheetId: 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx', 
    range: 'A1:C',
    valueRenderOption: "FORMATTED_VALUE",  
    dateTimeRenderOption: "SERIAL_NUMBER",  
    auth: authClient, 
  }

  try {
    const response = (await sheets.spreadsheets.values.get(request)).data;

    console.log(JSON.stringify(response, null, 2));
    data.payload=response
  } catch (err) {
    console.error(err);
  }
  return data
};


/* WRITE TO SHEET */
async function updateSheet () {
  const authClient = await authorize();
  const request = {
    spreadsheetId: 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx', 
    range: 'A7:C7', 
    valueInputOption: 'RAW', 
    insertDataOption: 'INSERT_ROWS',
    resource: {
      item: 'dummyname',
      dateLogged:'dummydate',
      expires:'dummy expire'
    },

    auth: authClient,
  };

  try {
    const response = (await sheets.spreadsheets.values.append(request)).data;

    console.log(JSON.stringify(response, null, 2));
  } catch (err) {
    console.error(err);
  }
}
```

my app.post

```
app.post('/api/updateSheet', (req,res)=>{
    updateSheet()
});
```

Comment: "TypeError: Cannot read property 'installed' of undefined at resolve (C:\Users\luther\Desktop\Pantree\index.js:50:69)" so what's in `index.js` on line 50? (and 49, and basically everything around it =)

Comment: @mike-pomax-kamermans I guess that's one of the odd parts because those lines are where my grabSheetData function is.....but that function works fine, I know each function requires a call to authorize() to get authorization using my token, but the authorize function goes from lines: 34-46

Comment: Well, it looks like the error occurs on this  line `const { client_secret, client_id, redirect_uris } = credentials.installed;` because `credentials` is `undefined`.  `credentials` is passed to `authorize(credentials)` as an argument.  So, somewhere you can calling authorize, you are not passing the right credentials.  You don't show the code where you call `authorize(credentials)` so there's not much else we can help with in that regard.

Comment: That's not weird. Remember to look up what errors mean: `UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning` means you have a promise somewhere, but you forgot the `.catch(....)`: in 100% of the cases, this is guaranteed going to lead to bugs, so browsers (and Node) warn you when you have a `.then(...)` without a `.catch(...)`. In this case, await "the thing", but _don't_ access `.data` until _after_ that await resolves and binds to `response`.

Comment: The unhandled rejection probably occurs in `grabSheetData()` when you do this `const authClient = await authorize(creds);`.  `authorize()` fails and you don't have a `try/catch` around this `await` so therefore you get an unhandled rejection error.  But, the root problem is that `creds` is not what it's supposed to be.  You should also have a `try/catch` around the `await` to catch errors, but that isn't the root problem here.

Answer (score 0):

I had forgotten to pass creds to my authorize call in my updateSheets() call

```
async function updateSheet () {
  const authClient = await authorize(creds); //PASS CREDS HERE
  const request = {
    spreadsheetId: '1VTiTgPvMvLlOVBhBfoMGrshfMMJJMMzoA6GesheWMPg', 
    range: 'A7:C7', 
    valueInputOption: 'RAW', 
    insertDataOption: 'INSERT_ROWS',
    resource: {
      item: 'dummyname',
      dateLogged:'dummydate',
      expires:'dummy expire'
    },

    auth: authClient,
  };

  try {
    const response = (await sheets.spreadsheets.values.append(request)).data;
    // TODO: Change code below to process the `response` object:
    console.log(JSON.stringify(response, null, 2));
  } catch (err) {
    console.error(err);
  }
}
```

Comment: And, you still aren't catching errors from some of your `await` statements.  Every `await` can throw a rejected promise.  You need to catch them somewhere in the call chain, if not locally, then in a caller.